# MatLab GUI: toggle buttons in toolbar (only one should be active)

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, togglebutton

I have a GUI in MatLab in which I want to have some (toggle) buttons with zoom functions.
My Problem is, that I want only one toggle button being active at the same time:
1) I click on toggle button A
2) Button A is active
3) Now I click on button B
4) Button A & B are active

But what I want is, that Button A's state goes to 'off' the moment I activate button B. Like the behaviour of the built in Matlab toolbars for plots.

Here is the code for my buttons:

```
%%% Zoom Toolbar
figureToolBar = uitoolbar;
% pointer button/all off
    % icon
    [img,~,alpha] = imread(fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox','matlab','icons',...
        'tool_pointer.png'));
    icon = double(img)/256/256;
    icon(~alpha) = NaN;
    % button
    uipushtool(figureToolBar,'Tooltip','Pan','CData',icon,...
        'ClickedCallback','zoom off; pan off;');
% pan button
    % icon
    [img,~,alpha] = imread(fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox','matlab','icons',...
        'tool_hand.png'));
    icon = double(img)/256/256;
    icon(~alpha) = NaN;
    % button
    uitoggletool(figureToolBar,'Tooltip','Pan','CData',icon,...
        'OnCallback','pan on','OffCallback','pan off');
% zoom in button
    % icon
    [img,~,alpha] = imread(fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox','matlab','icons',...
        'tool_zoom_in.png'));
    icon = double(img)/256/256;
    icon(~alpha) = NaN;
    % button
    uitoggletool(figureToolBar,'Tooltip','Zoom In','CData',icon,...
        'OnCallback','zoom on','OffCallback','zoom off');
% zoom out button
    % icon
    [img,~,alpha] = imread(fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox','matlab','icons',...
        'tool_zoom_out.png'));
    icon = double(img)/256/256;
    icon(~alpha) = NaN;
    % button
    uipushtool(figureToolBar,'Tooltip','Zoom Out','CData',icon,...
        'ClickedCallback','zoom out');
% zoom x button
    % icon
    [img,~,alpha] = imread(fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox','shared','sdi',...
        'web','MainView','release','SDI2','icons','toolstrip',...
        'ZoomInT_16.png'));
    icon = double(img)/256;
    icon(~alpha) = NaN;
    % button
    uitoggletool(figureToolBar,'Tooltip','Zoom X','CData',icon,...
        'OnCallback','zoom xon','OffCallback','zoom off');
% zoom y button
    % icon
    [img,~,alpha] = imread(fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox','shared','sdi',...
        'web','MainView','release','SDI2','icons','toolstrip',...
        'ZoomInY_16.png'));
    icon = double(img)/256;
    icon(~alpha) = NaN;
    % button
    uitoggletool(figureToolBar,'Tooltip','Zoom Y','CData',icon,...
        'OnCallback','zoom yon','OffCallback','zoom off');
```

If necessary, I can give a minimal working example with the *.m and *.fig file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use the callbacks for the toggle action to set the state of the others, for example something like this:

```
function toggleTooolbarTest
  hTool = uitoolbar;
  % Create 2 toolbar items - setting one to have a state 1      
  tog1 = uitoggletool(hTool,'Tooltip','Toggle 1', 'CData', rand(16,16,3), 'State', 'on' );
  tog2 = uitoggletool(hTool,'Tooltip','Toggle 2', 'CData', rand(16,16,3) );

  % Set the callback for each toggle passing itself and the other toggle
  %  to the callback
  set(tog1,'ClickedCallback',@(obj,event)ToggleToolbar(obj,tog2));
  set(tog2,'ClickedCallback',@(obj,event)ToggleToolbar(obj,tog1));
end
function ToggleToolbar ( primary, secondary )
  % Switch the "other" toolbar state based on the value of the 
  %   toolbar which the user clicked on.
  switch get ( primary, 'State' )
    case 'on'
      set ( secondary, 'State', 'off' );
    case 'off'
      set ( secondary, 'State', 'on' );
  end
end
```

Comment: I had this way on my mind, but how would you combine this with these build in zoom functions?

Comment: @Phab see the documentation for [`zoom`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zoom.html), specifically the `h = zoom(figure_handle)` syntax, which allows you to enable zoom for a specific figure.

Comment: @Phab I would replace the built in zoom toggle buttons with your own ones where you can control the state etc.... but they still have the same actions as pointed out in the earlier comment

Comment: after days of trying, I think I had to accept there is no other way ;-)